# Center footer div horizontally

Tags: html, css, center, footer

http://pixphoriad.haneuri.net/index2.php

The top div for the header centers fine but for some reason the content in the footer is not centered. Here's the css for the footer:

```
div#footer {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    position:relative;
    height:350px;
    clear: both;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

apply these rules to `center` tag...

```
overflow: auto;
display: inline-block;
```

Btw, center tag is obsolete, i had never seen it until now. But whatever..

I like overall site...It shows passion.

Comment: Apply to center tag? I just have it tagged in footer.php, though I agree, right there it's doing nothing, it's not part of my css file as it's own tag. Does it need to be?

Comment: you can make a `<div class='center'>` and then add `.center { ...rules above ... }` in css file.. Center tag includes all footer content.

Comment: @Kristin Please don't forget to mark this answer as accepted if it's the one you ended up using (click the gray checkmark to the left). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Define the `width` you want and give `margin` like this:

```
div#footer {
      width: 500px;
      margin: 0 auto; /* or `10px auto` to add margin top and bottom */
      text-align: center; /* align text center aligned*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you add the following lines to your `div#footer`:

```
overflow: auto;
display: inline-block;
```